# pg_prepare problems with Create role?

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi There i want to create a new postgresql role with a prepared statement:
My Code:

```
$stmt = pg_prepare($conn,"test","CREATE ROLE $1 WITH LOGIN PASSWORD $2 NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE");
    $result = pg_execute($conn,"test",array($username,$password));
    if (!$result){
        die("error in SQL query:".pg_last_error());
    }
```

But i get this error on execution: 
PHP Warning:  pg_prepare(): Query failed: FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »$1«

If i try a simple select:

```
$stmt = pg_prepare($conn,"test","Select * from pg_user where usename=$1");
```

everything works as expected.

Anyone have a hint? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [pg_escape_identifier()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pg-escape-identifier.php) to avoid SQL injection on dynamic items like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can not use a prepared statement for this purpose. The parameters of a prepared statement can only refer to data values (like in an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement, or in the `WHERE` example you give). The values for the role name and password in the `CREATE ROLE` statement need to be supplied as string literals.

Use of a prepared statement in `CREATE ROLE` is also not useful at all. A prepared statement is used to plan execution of a complex statement once and then execute it many times with different parameters. A `CREATE ROLE` statement is not complex and neither will you ever have enough statements to run in a single session to make a prepared statement useful, if it were possible to begin with.

Comment: ok and which way i should go to prevent sqlinjections and have a readable source?

Comment: You should build the entire string for the command in php and then feed it to PostgreSQL. The issue of SQL injections is a completely different matter. You should first ask yourself who will have access to this code? Do you really need to create new roles from your application, by an untrusted user (that is where SQL injections come from, after all)?